# react-native-video - Video stalls and then keeps playing

Tags: reactjs, video, stream, native

I am currently using react-native-video in my app. We are passing a m3u8 stream url to the video player. The stream does play, however after two seconds the onStall event is fired. Within 2-5 seconds the onResume event is then fired and the stream resumes ,although now 2-5 seconds behind.

My video is implemented as follows:

```
<Video
    key={index}
    ref={this.vPlayer}
    source={{uri: item.uri}}
    poster={item.poster}
    posterResizeMode="cover"
    style={styles.mediaPlayer}
    onError={(error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }}
    onPlaybackStalled={() => {
        console.log("Stalled");
    }}
    onBuffer={(data) => {
        console.log("Buffer", data);
    }}
    onVideoBuffer={() => {
        console.log("Video Buffer");
    }}
    onPlaybackResume={() => {
        console.log("Resume");
    }}
    muted={this.state.auctionMuted}
    playInBackground={false}
    resizeMode="cover"
    controls={true}
    paused={false}
/>
```

In the get a mixture of console logs from the various events I have being logged. The usual is:

```
Stalled
Resume
```

But I also sometimes get, where the errors seem to be occurring each 1 second frame:

```
Stalled
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -2147483648}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
{"error": {"extra": 0, "what": -38}}
```

This issue seems to only happen on Android, the iOS App streams fine.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,